# adding custom function into kendo observable array

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-observable

How do I add custom or extend kendo observable array ?
JS fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/balarvs/mctyswh2/3/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
/*   var ar = [
    { id: "10" }, 
    { id: "12" },
    { id: "20" }
]; */

if (![].getById) {
    Array.prototype.getById = function (id) {
        'use strict';
        var arr = Object(this);
        var found;
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            var item = arr[i];
            if (item.id == id) {
                found = item;
            }
        }
        return found;
    };
}
var obser=new kendo.data.ObservableArray( [
    { id: "10" },
    { id: "12" },
    { id: "20" }
]);
var bb = obser.getById("20");
if (bb != undefined) console.log(bb.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should *not* extend `Array` but `kendo.data.ObservableArray`. Your code should be something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    kendo.data.ObservableArray.prototype.getById = function (id) {
        'use strict';
        var arr = Object(this);
        var found;
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            var item = arr[i];
            if (item.id == id) {
                found = item;
            }
        }
        return found;
    };

    var obser=new kendo.data.ObservableArray( [
        { id: "10" },
        { id: "12" },
        { id: "20" }
    ]);
    var bb = obser.getById("23");
    if (bb != undefined) console.log(bb.id);
});
```

Your JSFiddle modified here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/mctyswh2/8/

Comment: thank you. worked fine. But I found another solution http://jsfiddle.net/balarvs/sa9Lngcy/2/

Comment: Do you really need that much code for this? If the only thing that you need is extending `ObservableArray` I would say that that's way too much code. Personal preferences!